# pam radius bypass same local user (exception user)

Tags: centos, ssh, authentication, pam, radius

Pam Radius login works with the following configuration.
However, it would be necessary for some users to perform local authentication. How can I solve this?

```
[xxxxxxxxxxx ~]# cat /etc/pam.d/sshd
#%PAM-1.0
auth    [success=done default=bad authinfo_unavail=bad ignore=ignore]  pam_radius_auth.so localifdown

auth       required     pam_sepermit.so
auth       substack     password-auth
auth       include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-auth      optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      password-auth
password   include      password-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params >
session    required     pam_namespace.so >
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      password-auth
session    include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-session   optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth required   pam_radius_auth.so
#
#auth      required     pam_sepermit.so
#auth       substack     password-auth
#auth       include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-auth      optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      password-auth
password   include      password-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params
session    required     pam_namespace.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      password-auth
session    include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-session   optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
```